# Displaying an array list with each element on a new line?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextarea

Code:

```
ArrayList <Integer> marks = new ArrayList();

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Collections.addAll(marks, (Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText())));
    marks.add(Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText()));
    for (int j =0; j < marks.size(); j++) {
        markdisplayTextArea.setText(Integer.toString(marks.get(j)));
}
```

This program is supposed to display each number on a new line in a JTextArea when the user types it in and presses the "add" button.

It displays each number but only one at a time. I want each number entered to be displayed on a new line in ascending. So if the user entered 4 numbers, say, 78, 92, 54, and 21, I want them displayed like this:

21
54
78
92

Comment: Looks like homework. If it is, then add the homework tag.

Comment: It is simple: You want the numbers to be appended to the text which is already there. Then you have to *write code* to concatenate. Try something and then let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work, markdisplayTextArea.setText(Integer.toString(marks.get(j))) + " " + (marks);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are resetting the text in every single loop in the last loop of the code.

Just write a loop to concatenate the numbers into one String (adding `\n` after every number), then set the text of `JTextArea` to the concatenated result. Since `JTextArea` supports multiline text, it should be displayed correctly.

```
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
for (Integer mark: marks) {
  text.append(mark.toString()).append('\n');
}
markdisplayTextArea.setText(text.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how exactly to do this. Also, I'm using NetBeans so do I set the multi-line text support through the "properties" tab? I can see rows and columns under this tab but not multi-line support

Comment: JTextArea supports multi-line by itself. No need to set any options.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work, 
markdisplayTextArea.setText(Integer.toString(marks.get(j))) + " "        + (marks);

Comment: Thanks but I get this error, cannot find symbol: method StringBuffer()

Comment: Thanks much! I also deleted this line since it was making the number entered show twice: marks.add(Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText()));